# Is "how" a subordinator between independent clauses?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, subordinate-clauses

> We will look at how this is used.

My question is this:

1. Is the word *how* a subordinator in this sentence? If not, what is it?
2. Are "We will look at" and "this is used" two independent clauses?
3. Are these independent clauses connected by a word "how"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But the word *how* is not a relative word (either adverb, adjective or pronoun) and does not appear in relative clauses. It is an interrogative adverb/adjective or a declarative subordinator. Very importantly *subordinator* is a term comparable to *conjunction*. John Lawler's point there is that being a relative*wh-* word does not make a word a conjunction. However, the word *how* does indeed appear as a subordinator in informal English. So this question is substantively different from that one.

Comment: Your risking annoying users here, because this question is identical to a question you posted on ELL. I have answered it here, because I believe this is where the question should have been asked in the first place.

Comment: @Araucaria Are you saying that John Lawler's  'Complementizers introduce complement clauses (including embedded wh-question complements)' is not the correct answer here? [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-complementizer-1689770) concurs:  << "wh-" questions always begin with a complementizer, including such words as who, whom, whose, what, which, why, when, where and how. >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that's right, that isn't reallly the answer to this question. JL'sanswer there states that the those words are adverbs, not conjunctions (read subordinators). The point here is that *how* - unlike *why* and the other adverbs discussed there - *CAN* be either an adverb or a conjunction/subordinator. So the question is why it is one or the other in this sentence.

Comment: I'd reread this. JL says: 'Complementizers introduce complement clauses (including embedded wh-question complements), adverbs introduce adverbial clauses, etc.' He is putting this usage in the complementiser class, not the adverb class and not the conjunction class.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's still live at ELL and has been reduplicated here.